# Android WifiManager.enableNetwork taking 10sec

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

We are using Android API WifiManager.enableNetwork(netid, true) to switch between desired wifi network. The switching is working, but it takes around 10-11 seconds to disable current network and get connected with new network. Why this delay is there? Is there any workaround to make it fast switching?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no way to speed that process up. It's just the nature of WiFi -- connecting to a network can take a long time.

If your problem is that the `enableNetwork` call "freezes" your UI, just create another thread.

Comment: Thanks, We are already calling this in thread. Is there any other API or any low level method to do fast switching of the network?

Comment: Not that I know of. And I'd be surprised if there was -- as I said, this is the nature of WiFi.